# Codeigniter JOIN using two tables - need data from both

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join, relational-database

I am trying to create a fixture for two teams in Codeigniter. My database was built in MySQL Workbench. I have a table for team

```
team

team_id
team_name
team_logo
```

I also have a table for fixture.

```
fixture 

fixture_id
fixture_text
fixture_comp
fixture_type
fixture_level
fixture_date
```

The relationship between these two tables is many to many which creates a JOIN table called team_has_fixture which has a composite PK made up from team_id and fixture_id

```
team_has_fixture

team_id
fixture_id
```

I am trying to create a fixture that uses all the data from the fixture table and the team logo for the two teams involved in the fixture from the team table.

e.g layout of fixture will look like this - team 1 logo - fixture details - team 2 logo

I want to achieve this in a single query but don't know how.

I can get all the info from both tables individually without problem. I can also get the fixture data from the JOIN table team_has_fixtures using the following code in my Model;

fixtures model

```
function fixtures() 

    {

        //Query the team_has_fixture table for every record and row  

        $results = array(); 

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('team_has_fixture');

        $this->db->join('team', 'team_has_fixture.team_team_id = team.team_id');
        $this->db->join('fixture', 'team_has_fixture.fixture_fixture_id= fixture.fixture_id');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
         $results = $query->result();
        }

        return $results;   

    }
```

I am unsure how to incorporate into a join the code to get the data I need to create the fixture that will include the logos for both teams

Comment: it's better to have another column in team_has_fixture called team_id2 and then you can find the logos for both teams in one fixture. team_id and team_id2 reference teams table.

Comment: Sam thanks - I think I understand how that will work. now to work out how to write the JOIN that gives me values from both tables

Comment: It may be helpful for you to present some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, a fixture is an item involving two teams.  Each fixture has a unique id number, so if team 7 and team 5 are involved in fixture 3, then there will be two rows in `team_has_fixture`, like so.

```
team_id    fixture_id
   5            3
   7            3
```

I also assume you can rely on your system to refrain from assigning just one team to a fixture, or assigning more than two teams.

You need a way to extract both teams for each fixture.  This subquery, in SQL, will give you one row per fixture with the two teams mentioned.  By using `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` this query excludes fixtures with other numbers of teams than two.

```
 SELECT MIN(team_id) AS team_a_id,
        fixture      AS fixture_id,
        MAX(team_id) AS team_b_id
   FROM team_has_fixture
  GROUP BY fixture_id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Then you can build an SQL query to deliver the result set you mentioned.

```
 SELECT t1.team_logo  AS team_a_logo,
        f.*,
        t2.team_logo  AS team_b_logo
  FROM  fixture AS f
  JOIN  (
           SELECT MIN(team_id) AS team_a_id,
                  fixture      AS fixture_id,
                  MAX(team_id) AS team_b_id
             FROM team_has_fixture
            GROUP BY fixture_id
           HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
        ) AS j ON f.fixture_id = j.fixture_id
  JOIN team AS t1 ON t1.team_id = j.team_a_id
  JOIN team AS t2 ON t2.team_id = j.team_b_id
```

See what's going on? We take your two-way join table and aggregate it into a three way join subquery. We then do the three way join, and there's your result.

Please excuse me; I don't know how to render such a query into Codeigniter. But this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the response to my question. I tried putting the teams into  a fixture like you have - inserting two rows into team_has_fixture under `team_id and fixture_id ` and when I did a test query on the table it returned two  identical fixtures i.e it created two fixtures instead of one fixture featuring the two teams